# How can I concatenate text into a string using a variable in applescript?

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to concatenate at variable within a path name string to make this script more efficient.
This is the code I have so far. But I can't seem to find the right syntax needed in order to set the  variable in the string.

```
    set vserver to POSIX file "/Volumes/johndoe"
    set user to "johndoe" as string

    set source to POSIX file "/Users/johndoe/Documents"

    tell application "Finder"

        duplicate source to vserver with replacing
    end tell
```

I want johndoe to be replaces by variable user to make the code more maintainable for the future. My ultimate goal is to be able to copy multiple home folders including: movies, pictures, documents etc... onto a shared server.

I tried doing this

```
"/Users/" & user & "/Desktop"
```

But I received this error:

> "Finder got an error: Handler can’t handle objects of this class."
>   number -10010

Comment: "My ultimate goal is to be able to copy multiple home folders ... onto a shared server." -- Why? (e.g. If you're trying to do backups, there are far, far better solutions: Time Machine, rsync, various commercial packages.)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hard coding it, you can get the path to your desktop like this:

```
set source to path to desktop
```

Comment: so, what if I want to do multiple home folders. Do I have to do a duplicate process for each or can I just do them all in one swoop?

Comment: and is there a way to set the user the actual account username so that the script is mobile?